# NSTImer & sending args throught selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, selector, nstimer

I am trying to do animation. At some point I want to execute a method through `NSTimer`. I need to pass in 1 argument. This I do it through `userInfo` in `NSTimer`. In the selector method I am trying to access back this passed arg. But when I actually run this I get the following exception. It says invalid argument. What am I doing wrong?

> "Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[FLOViewController **hideCellView**]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1681d0'"

```
-(void)hideCellView:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    UITableViewCell *cellView = (UITableViewCell *)[timer userInfo];
    [cellView addSubview:self.extrasView];
    return;
}

-(IBAction)showExtras:(id)sender
{
    if(![sender isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]]) return;  // be paranoid
    self.searchResTable.scrollEnabled = NO;

    //Get the exact cell where the click happened
    UIButton *button          = sender; 
    CGPoint correctedPoint    = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.searchResTable]; 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath    = [self.searchResTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:correctedPoint];
    UITableViewCell *cellView = [self.searchResTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //now run animation
    CGContextRef context      = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                           forView:cellView 
                             cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(hideCellView) 
                                   userInfo:cellView 
                                    repeats:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return;
}
```

Comment: The `context` in `+[UIView beginAnimations:context:` is not the graphics context and you can safely set it to `NULL` unless you are implementing the completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed the wrong selector.

```
selector:@selector(hideCellView)
```

It should be,

```
selector:@selector(hideCellView:)
```

That said you should consider sending the index path of the table view cell rather than the cell itself as cells are reused. You can get the cell later using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method the table view in the `hideCellView:` method.

If you are looking to set a delay in the animation then use the `setAnimationDelay:` method rather that using `NSTimer`.

Comment: I figured about the `:`, thanks though. But what interests me  is the info abt tableCells. Yes I reuse my table cells. You mean since the cells are reused, passing cell object around is not advisable? Is this one of those "best practices" or it's a must?

Comment: Well consider this scenario. You've set a timer to trigger in a second. The user scrolls the list. Your cell goes off screen. If you are reusing cells, the cell will be reused for an another index path. And when the method is triggered, you will update the wrong cell. But when you pass the index path, you can get the correct cell if it is onscreen. If has been scrolled off, you will get `nil` using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so your action `addSubview:` will have no effect. That way you won't update the wrong cell.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is to replace the `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval ...` line with:

`[self performSelector:@selector(hideCellView:) withObject:cellView afterDelay:0.5]`

But this is not the correct way to handle running code after an animation.  Check out blocks based animation using something like `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`.  [Apple docs are a good place to start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).